# Como dividir corretamente um <th> no html?

Tags: html5

Eu quero fazer uma tabela, onde os `<th>` se separem em três, uma linha em cima e uma linha quebrada em dois embaixo, porém não consigo separar o `<th>` em dois como o `<td>` já que usamos o `colspan`, tentei fazer umas gambiarras, mas não ficaria bom, pois depois teria que ficar responsiva, é possível fazer uma tabela igual essa?

meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ITEM A
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ITEM B
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                        ITEM C
                        <p>ITEM D | ITEM E<p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <td>
                A
            </td>
            <td>
                B
            </td>
            <td>
                C1
            </td>
            <td>
                C2
            </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não precisa colocar 'resolvido' no título da pergunta. Você já marcou a resposta como aceita e isso basta. :)

Comment: Valeu @emanuelsn! Sou novo aqui na comunidade, não sabia disso, rs.

Comment: Tranquilo, cara. Seja bem vindo ao SOpt. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas eu faria assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>    
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <!-- PRIMEIRO LINHA -->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><!-- OCUPA DUAS LINHAS -->
                ITEM A
            </td>

            <td rowspan="2"><!-- OCUPA DUAS LINHAS -->
                ITEM B
            </td>

            <td colspan="2"><!-- OCUPA DUAS COLUNAS-->
                ITEM C
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- FIM PRIMEIRA LINHA -->

        <!-- SEGUNDA LINHA -->
        <tr> <!-- TENHO OS DOIS ITENS, IGNORO AS DUAS PRIMEIRAS COLUNAS POIS JÁ DEFINI QUE AS DA PRIMEIRA LINHA OCUPARAM ESSA LINHA -->
            <td>
                ITEM D
            </td>
            <td>
                ITEM E
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- FIM DA SEGUNDA LINHA E COMEÇO DA TERCEIRA -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                A
            </td>

            <td>
                B
            </td>

            <td>
                C1
            </td>

            <td>
                C2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- FIM DA TERCEIRA LINHA -->

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lvcs, Perfeito +1, era a solução que eu estava procurando, muito obrigado!

Comment: @DevRyu, comentei o código para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Melhor ainda @lvcs, parece um problema fácil, mas tem que montar com calma a tabela, ainda mais para novatos como eu na montagem de telas responsivas.

Comment: Para sites responsivos, em tabela sugiro usar as classes do `bootstrap`, se não estiver usando rs, dá menos trabalho..

Comment: Estou usando sim, rs (ainda não consigo fazer na mão sem), mas para funcionar, precisava dessa tabela que você gentilmente forneceu, com o html correto.